# Signal on various frequencies, about 2.5k bandwidth, sounds like a broken motor turning: What is it?

Tags: hf, signal-identification, swl

There are a number of frequencies, where a certain type of signal can be heard. The characteristics is, that every occurrence takes about 2.5k bandwidth, and it is transmitted in a continuous way. Specific is as well, that it looks like a rather broad carrier, and sounds the same in AM or L/USB.

See the following screenshot of a SDR, where you can observer them three times around 8300 khz:
[image: SDR Screenshot]

An audio example of it is at the following link (WAV, ca. 150k, ca. 5 sec): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4ecO4IudzvrOVRUX242MkQtbFU/view?usp=sharing

My question: What is it? As it is constantly transmitted I suspect it could be a weather radar. Can anyone state what it actually is?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  Please consider taking [the tour](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help) to get the most from this site.   It sounds to me like [DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Radio_Mondiale) but it's too narrow to be that.

Answer (score 5):

These are data transmissions using [OFDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_frequency-division_multiplexing).

They are government or military point to point data links. I would expect that the data would be encrypted.